# Bash exec command not found

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

CMD='sh -c "echo 123"'
exec "$CMD"
```

And I'm running it like so:

```
./test.sh 
./test.sh: 4: exec: sh -c "echo 123": not found
```

Why is it not found?
Running `sh -c "echo 123"` from console works.

The real problem I'm trying to solve is in this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
# or first arg is `something.conf`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ] || [ "${1%.conf}" != "$1" ]; then
        set -- 'redis-server' "$@"
fi

# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'redis-server' -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
        find . \! -user redis -exec chown redis '{}' +
        exec su-exec redis "$0" "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'redis-server' ]; then
        exec sh -c "$@ | log-converter"
fi

exec "$@"
~
```

which is an edited file from https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/84c36a0967bcfa8a9c39cb899464785c5f2cf5ef/6.0/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh.

My goal is to run the redis server but pipe the output to log-converter, and the output of the log-converter to be displayed on stdout. How should I write it so that it works?

My script executes the line `exec sh -c "$@ | log-converter"` but then I see nothing on the screen and it blocks.

If I just try to call `redis-server | log-converter`, it works fine.

Comment: Because `exec` expects the first argument to be the name of a command, not the whole command line.

Comment: Why are you using `exec` in the first place?

Comment: You are perhaps confusing `exec` with `eval`, *neither* of which you should be using here. See [BashFaq 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Try running the command `'sh -c "echo 123"'` on the command line -- including the outside quotes -- and you'll see the same behavior. You're over-quoting things in your script.

Comment: See `man execve` for the underlying syscall family that `exec` calls through to. Just as in C `execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", "echo 123", NULL)` is correct and `execlp("sh", "sh -c \"echo 123\"", NULL)` is wrong, `exec sh -c "echo 123"` is correct and `exec "sh -c \"echo 123\""` is wrong. That said, `execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", "\"echo", "123\"", NULL)` is *also* wrong, and that's what you'll get from `exec $CMD` without the quotes for the reasons BashFAQ #50 describes; the link chepner provided above is precisely on-point.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the reply, I edited the question. I thought just simplifying this problem would be enough, but it still isn't working as I would like it to.

Comment: There's no `exec "$CMD"` in the script (`$@` is a special parameter, it doesn't work like ordinary variables). And your problem isn't a "not found" error. I can't think of a good reason why you're not seeing the `log-converter` output.